# unity c# hide text after using .text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

So i want to hide a text. I usually i use .setActive(true/ false) but if i want to change the text during the game running i use GameObject.text

here comes the problem: if i use Gameobject.text i can no longe use gameobject.setActive anymore.

FYI it is supposed to be highscore which is running in the back and gets revealed once you achieved the games goal.

So i made a SerializedField for the text and used .Find to find the right object

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject gameende;

GameObject gameendee = GameObject.Find("gameende");
```

set it on false so its hidden

```
gameendee.SetActive(false);
```

got my score int

```
punkte = 120 - (vergroessert * 10)+ ei;
```

got my score in the text

```
gameendee.text = "Dein Punktestand: " + punkte.ToString();
```

and now I wanted to do:

```
gameendee.SetActive(true);
```

but that doesnt work.

what would be the alternative way?

Comment: There's no reason the SetActive(true) shouldn't work in this context, given what you've shown us so far.  If you remove the SetActive() calls, does it work?

Comment: Yes, i guess. I have set on false at the beginning but i see that the text changes during the game its just not shown because of setActive(false). but i cant get it to true after using .text. 

The error message says that "text" has no definition for setActive

Comment: It seems that you actually use `Text gameende` not `GameObject gameende` ? => `gameende.gameObject.setActive(true);`

Comment: i used GameObject gameendee = GameObject.Find("gameende");

Comment: Well, that can't be right, because you set 'gameendee.text', and GameObjects don't have a 'text' property...?

Comment: Please go through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us a complete snippet we can work with

Comment: You are probably mistaking gameObjects and the components attached to them. They are not the same, gameObject is simply a "bucket" for components. Some types of components have text properties, others don't. But  "the bucket" i.e. gameObject that contains them never have text. BTW always use English when naming things in code, otherwise you will surely end in a position where very few will be able to understand your code and help/cooperate with you.

Answer (score 1):

thats because "GameObject.Find()" looks only for active game objects.

instead you should look up for your gameobject only once and store a reference within an variable. This is also muhc more performant!